# Why does cin.get() get stuck on newline characters?

Tags: c++, string, get

Code:

```
char s[20];
cout<<"enter ur name"<<endl;
cin.get(s,20);
cout<<s<<endl;

char s2[30];
cout<<"enter ur name again"<<endl;
cin.get(s2,30);
cout<<s2<<endl;

char s3[40];
cout<<"enter ur name once again"<<endl;
cin.get(s3,40);
cout<<s3<<endl; 
return 0;
```

Output:

```
enter ur name
Albert Einstein
Albert Einstein
enter ur name again

enter ur name once again
```

If I input "Albert Einstein" in s and then press enter, I know s2 will get newline character(present in stream due to previous pressing of enter key).Now stream is empty. Why s3 is not taking a fresh input? Why s3 is also taking newline character if I haven't pressed enter key again?

Answer (score 1):

Per [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/), `get()` leaves the trailing newline in the stream:

> The delimiting character is **not** extracted from the input sequence if found, and remains there as the next character to be extracted from the stream (see [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) for an alternative that *does* discard the delimiting character).

Comment: Note: I'm aware of people's [general dislike for cplusplus.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/d2agm7/httpwwwcpluspluscom_or_httpswwwcppreferencecom/). Nevertheless, its writeup for `istream::get()` is a lot easier to digest than [cppreference's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: Did i get that right that all subsequent calls to `get` will then return immediatlely until that newline is read by some other function?